# Why aren't nasdaq.com and yahoo.com removed when I clear Safari website data?

Tags: safari, macos, privacy

When I clear website data in Safari (Preferences --> Privacy --> Manage Website Data... --> Remove All), nasdaq.com and yahoo.com remain in the list.  Is this a known issue, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are likely "perma cookies" which are cookies that use javascript and other methods to make the cookies persistent *even when you have explicitly removed all cookies.* Which is annoying as hell and a known issue.

I found an [Apple discussions post that purports to show you how to delete these](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7764311?start=0&tstart=0).

Which boils down to

> So the path is:
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Safari/Databases/__IndexedDB/
> ```
>
> Just delete the folder of the cookie you no longer want

Comment: Just one of the reasons I stopped using pretty much every service associated with Yahoo and permanently browse in "Incognito Mode."

Comment: Thanks.  In fact I ended up deleting the entire contents of `~/Library/Safari/Databases/`

Comment: Further remark: I don't think this was due to "perma cookies".  The data persisted even when no browser window was open, so the websites in question could not have been responsible for the behavior.  More likely a Safari bug.